# removing repeated elements for more than n times

Tags: java, arrays

So as u can see i am trying to remove the element if it is repeated more than n times.

for example:
{1,2,4,5,6,5} and every element can be repeated once then i should return {1,2,4,5,6}

here is what i came up with up till now :

```
 public static int[] deleteNth(int[] elements, int maxOcurrences) {
    int times[] = new int[elements.length];
    for(int i =0;i<elements.length;i++){
        for(int j =0;i<elements.length;j++){
            if(elements[i]==elements[j]){
                times[i]++;
                if(times[i]>maxOcurrences){
                    System.arraycopy(elements, j+1 , elements, j, elements.length - 1 - j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

is this right ? if not how can i correct it 
(go easy on me as iam still a newbie),thanks

Comment: i strongly recommend to use `arraylist` instead of array and let the arraylist handle to logic to `remove` element while using `contains`, though use set

Comment: Your nested loop's condition should be `j<elements.length`

Comment: You should use `j = i + 1`. No need to do more work

Comment: Is it OK to sort the array ? If yes, sort the array first and go through the array and replace the duplicates with next unique element as you go through the array, the index at which you last replaced will give you the length of the new array, then do Arrays.copyOf( ... ). If it is not OK to sort the array then create an arraylist , add to it if not already present, then return array using list.toArray()

Comment: @GalAbra Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @Mitchel0022 Ok :)

Comment: @SomeDude actually it is not possible to sort the array the elements need to have the same order i will try to do the latter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a HashMap to store the elements in key value pair, where key will be your numbers and value will be the how many times it occurs . For example in your given input array HashMap will look like below

```
1->1
2->1
4->1
5->2
6->1
```

Then you can use contains methods and check the value for the key , if value of key is greater than 1 , then remove it.

Comment: Greater than **maxOcurrences**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using java 8 (or superior), you can take advantage of Collectors:

- You can groupBy each element of the array and count the number of occurrences of that element.
- You can then filter the result and get the list of elements whose number of occurrences is less than the limit of repetitions.

Some code (imports omitted):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(filterByRepeatedTimes(groupByRepeatedTimes(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5)), 2));
    }

    private static Map<Integer, Long> groupByRepeatedTimes(final List<Integer> arr) {
        return arr.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    }

    private static List<Integer> filterByRepeatedTimes(final Map<Integer, Long> repetitionsMap, final int nTimes) {
        return repetitionsMap.keySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(k -> repetitionsMap.get(k) < nTimes)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Or if you just want to remove duplicates:

```
System.out.println(Stream.of(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Hope that helps.